# Python GUI, UART inputs not changing, stm32f3

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyserial, stm32, usart

I am using the stm32f3 discovery board to get sensor measurements and send them via USART to a python GUI. The usart works and can also be viewed in the python debugger. However when I use the plt functions to create a simple graph to display each point, the usart values do not change. Without the plt functions to draw the GUI, I can receive varying values from the USART.

Here is my code:

```
import serial
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim

ser = serial.Serial( 
    port='COM3',
    baudrate=115200, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, 
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, 
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1000)

plt.show()
plt.ion()  

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)  
count=1  

while True:
        line = ser.readline()
        linenum = line.split(',')
        [x.strip() for x in linenum]
        del linenum[-1]
        print(linenum)
        count = count+1

        if count > 2:
                hour = int(linenum[0])
                minute = int(linenum[1])
                second = int(linenum[2])
                subsecond = int(linenum[3])
                ADC1_Averaged = int(linenum[4])
                ADC2_Averaged = int(linenum[5])
                ADC1_Der = int(linenum[6])
                ADC2_Der = int(linenum[7])
                ADC3_Averaged = int(linenum[8])
                ADC4_Averaged = int(linenum[9])

                plt.plot(count-3,ADC1_Averaged, 'bo')
                time.pause
                plt.draw()   

ser.close()
```

I receive a string like this:

```
['8', '35', '11', '196', '196', '225', '0', '0', '182', '148']
```

from the USART where the first four values are the time in hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds and they will change as time goes on. However the rest of the values are the sensor measurements and they will remain static with the plt functions. Without the plt functions they will vary with different sensor inputs.

I put it in an `if` statement because usually the first `readline` is not read properly and by the second count the USART is able to send all the values.

Comment: you should read as many lines as you can at a time I suspect the plotting is taking long enough that the serial buffer is full so you are pulling old data by iterating one line at a time ... or clear the serial buffer each time you plot ... (`ser.flush()` ) ... but you wil probably recieve some partial lines

Comment: I just created a minimal test case for the plotting part, and it seems to work just fine. What happens if you remove the plotting code and instead just `print(ADC1_Averaged)` in the loop, do you see that value change? Another thing, potentially unrelated: did you mean to use `time.sleep(seconds)` instead of `time.pause`?

Comment: If I remove the plotting tools, the printed values will change appropriately to the change in the sensors. Yes I did mean to use time.sleep(0.01), I was just testing to use time.pause to see if it would help my result.